# Some posts returning 404 instead of displaying post

Tags: posts, permalinks, 404-error

I'm having a problem with my Wordpress install. All of a sudden some of my posts return 404 errors when I try to go to their permalink. My post names are all numbers and this started happening when my numbered posts went over 1000.

So for example, this post works correctly:
http://kidlolly.com/post/999/

But this one returns a 404:
http://kidlolly.com/post/1000/

Any clue what might be the root of the problem? I am suspect maybe my .htaccess file but I admit I am not super savvy on .htaccess so I'm not quite sure what to look for. I am running a few "security" plugins that affect the .htaccess but since it isn't a problem for posts 1-999 I am not sure what to look for.

Here's where I think the problem might be in .htaccess file (if that is indeed the case), anyone able to help me interpret it?

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(&#x22;|&#x27;|&#x3C;|&#x3E;|&#x5C;|&#x7B;|&#x7C;).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F|127\.0).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are these permalinks generated? they appear to be sequential and not based on post ID.

Comment: They are the title of the post. I title each post in sequential order so the actual page title is "1000" or "999" etc. (It's manual not automated)

Comment: well, I've figured out what's happening, though I'm not sure at the moment how to fix it. Your post permalink matches the year archive rewrite rule because it's a 4 digit number, so WordPress is trying to load an archive for the year 1000, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the date rewrite rule is picking up your post permalink and trying to load a year archive instead of your single post. Since it appears you don't use date URLs on your site, you can change the date structure so it no longer clashes. Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file, then visit the `Settings > Permalinks` page in Admin to flush the rewrite rules:

```
function wpa82820_date_structure(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'date/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa82820_date_structure' );
```

This changes date URLs from `/2013/01/23/` to `/date/2013/01/23/` so they no longer clash with 4 digit single post permalinks.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help! I would never have been able to figure that out on my own.