# Wordpress with static posts page and custom permalink structure doesn't find posts with numeric permalinks

Tags: posts, permalinks

I've setup a static posts page named "Journal", `mydomain.com/journal`. 
This page now lists my 15 latest posts. All fine this long.

I'm able to access each post individually by going to `mydomain.com/postname`.
I want to change this so I'm able to access each post individually by going to `mydomain.com/journal/postname`.

If I change the permalink structure to `mydomain.com/journal/%postname%/` I can access posts with a permalink like `mydomain.com/journal/im-just-a-regular-post/` just fine.

But if I go with a numeric permalink so I end up with an url such as `mydomain.com/journal/12345` or a more complex (the endgame here) such as `mydomain.com/journal/99058672222` it'll just serve me up the content of the posts page without even redirecting me.

If I revert the permalink settings to `mydomain.com/%postname%/`I can access my post at `mydomain.com/99058672222` just fine. Why's that? Can I get around this somehow?

**UPDATE**
I installed Debug Bar

This is what I get with `mydomain.com/journal/regular-old-post`

#### Request:

journal/regular-old-post

#### Query String:

name=regular-old-post

#### Matched Rewrite Rule:

journal/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$

#### Matched Rewrite Query:

name=regular-old-post&page=

And with `mydomain.com/journal/99058672222` I get:

#### Request:

journal/99058672222

#### Query String:

page=%2F99058672222&pagename=journal

#### Matched Rewrite Rule:

(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$

#### Matched Rewrite Query:

pagename=journal&page=%2F99058672222

I can clearly see that they're different but I know too little about the mechanics of how the rewriting stuff works in WP. Any pointers?

Comment: maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82820/some-posts-returning-404-instead-of-displaying-post) is your issue?

Comment: Is the name of the post 99058672222 or is that the post ID ?

Comment: @nothingtosee I've set the permalink to 99058672222 manually, the name is actually something else.

Comment: @Milo I applied that piece of code, but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

With some help I was able to get it working with this:

```
add_action('init', 'journal_urls');
  function journal_urls() {
      add_rewrite_rule(
          '^journal/([^/]*)$',
          'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
          'top'
      );
  }
```

Maybe someone can benefit from this in the future.