# Wordpress can generate numeric permalinks, which then 404

Tags: permalinks, urls, 404-error

I know why setting a numerical permalink for a post would mean Wordpress confuses page name and number.

However, I notice on the site I am working on (Wordpress 4), that you can edit the permalink to contain a number and also if the title of the page is a number, then it  saves with a numerical permalink.  These pages then 404.

Is this just a bug with Wordpress or is something broken on my site? Should Wordpress be validating the permalink so a numeric one is not possible?

Links are being generated on the site by the PHP `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`.

If it should be validating the links, at what point does it validate them, eg does it do it on save, or before outputting the link to the front end.

Comment: what is your permalink structure, and can you give us an example permalink that generates a 404?

Comment: Permalinks are set to use Post name.  Basically, any fully numerical value does not work eg 1234.  Things like 1234a, 1234_1 work fine.  Invalid characters get replaced with a dash, and turned into a valid URL.  Also: entering the number as an ID of an existing article also 404s.

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82832/4771).